# How can I safely remove a cobbler from a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: gpio, hardware, pi-2

I recently received a Raspberry Pi 2 B kit from Adafruit, which includes [a cobbler](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2029).

My Pi is also in a clear case, from which I don't want to remove it (I'm somewhat afraid I'll break it in half getting it out, it was frightening enough putting it in).

This means I have very little space to get my fingers around the Pi side of the cobbler when I want to take it off. I don't want to resort to using a screwdriver or other implement to pry it off, but I also don't want to try to pull it off with the ribbon cable.

What's the best way to take a cobbler off a Pi with a case? Is the ribbon cable strong enough to (repeatedly) pull the connector off the board?

Comment: Why remove it you can just disconnect it from the breadboard, which you likely can do with fewer problems. You can then wrap it around the case and secure it with an elastic band.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like there isn't really a good way to do this, not because no one has ever thought about it but because anyone who has would have taken it into account before getting the equipment together.

I have a few different cases from various suppliers.  The nicest looking one is a pibow, but it is a total PITA in practical terms.  It doesn't snap together, it screws together -- in layers, with four little tiny plastic screws that have little tiny plastic nuts on the end.  It does have appropriate slots to run a camera or GPIO cable, but if these are things you want to be frequently attaching and detaching, this is obviously the *wrong* case.  I have a 6" cable on the GPIOs that I just leave attached; when there is nothing on the other end it is short enough to tuck underneath and is not particularly awkward for me.

I have another very plain, clear plastic case which has a cutout over top of the GPIOs, making it easy to attach and remove anything.  This is much more convenient although it does not provide as much protection.  If I were to throw that pi in a backpack I'd put it inside something else first.

There are a great variety of pi cases around both in terms of material used (bamboo, acrylic, aluminum, etc.) and form.  If you have a good idea of what purpose the case is to serve and not serve, you have plenty of options to choose from (ignoring availability and cost as factors).  Most of them are probably also easy to modify.

Put another way, there is no right way to compensate for the wrong equipment other than replacing it.  If you are happy enough making do, then live with it.  I love that pibow case despite the fact that it is dysfunctional.  If you want a worse example of making do with the wrong equipment, [take a close look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kYFp.jpg) at my solution to being too impatient to order a cobbler; those pins were bent one at a time with pliers and getting it actually attached to the breadboard is not worthwhile.  But while it lasted it worked fine.